# What's wrong with my code - Notification - no sound no vibrate

Tags: android, audio, notifications, default

I seem to have a problem with my code.
I have created a test activity, just to see what's wrong, still I can't.

```
public class test extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    String extra = "test";

    NotificationManager myNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, test.class);

    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, 
            extra, 
            System.currentTimeMillis());
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 
            0,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "title", "text", pendingIntent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.flags |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
    notification.flags |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    myNotificationManager.notify(33, notification);

}
}
```

I get no sound and/or vibrate when the notification pops.

I looked at the settings of my phone, and they are ok, no silent, default sound - enabled.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This...

```
notification.flags |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
notification.flags |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
notification.flags |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
```

should be...

```
notification.defaults|= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
notification.defaults|= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
notification.defaults|= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
```

Answer (score 13):

For all default values (Sound, Vibrate & Light) in 1 line of code you can use:

```
notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
```

this is the equivalent of

```
notification.defaults|= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
notification.defaults|= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
notification.defaults|= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
```

make sure you set permissions for vibrate in your Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```